# GoogleApiClient's enableAutoManage() needs a fragment activity but I have an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, google-api-client

I want to logout from google account which is integrated into my application. I have this function

```
   public void logoutFromGooglePlus(Activity a) {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .build();
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(a.getBaseContext())
                .enableAutoManage(a /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {


                        }
                    });
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();   // It can send user to onConnected(), call logout again from there
        }
    }
```

As you can see I need to do it in an activity but here I have a problem enableAutoManage needs a fragmentActivity as input. But I have an activity. Can I  cast activity as fragmentActivity easily?or there is some other methods to do it?
thanks

Comment: Yes you can pass your current any activity type.

Comment: @james BUT IT gives me the error that it need fragment activity..I just cast my activity and it will work?

Comment: it will work only if your Activity is a FragmentActivity really.

Comment: @VladMatvienko But It is a simple AppCompatActivity what other choices do I have?

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` **is** a `FragmentActivity`. You'd better change `public void logoutFromGooglePlus(Activity a)` to `public void logoutFromGooglePlus(FragmentActivity a)`

Comment: @VladMatvienko wow. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same problem as you but it works when i changed from activity to AppCompatActivity.

Hope it helps.